# Regex for Alphanumeric, spaces and symbols, Doesn't match like i need

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regular expression that matches :

-alphanumeric with spaces 
-these symbols and letters

```
á é í ó ú ñ Ñ ,.( ) ! - + % $
```

I tried with this, but it didn't match like i need:

```
[\w áéíóúñÑ,.\(\)\!\-\+\%\$]
```

What's wrong in this regex??

I'm using knockoutjs with knockout validation

```
.extend({pattern:{message:"No valid.",params:"[\w áéíóúñÑ,.\(\)\!\-\+\%\$]"}});
```

tested on chrome, firefox, IE10 and Safari browser.

Comment: "but didnt match like i need", what unexpected behavior occurs?

Comment: Don't forget that the _String_ literal `'\w\-'` becomes _String_ `w-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the special `\` escape character to place an actual `\` in the string. Also, you do not need to escape all these characters, just the ones that have a special meaning within the brackets.

Try with:

```
"[\\w áéíóúñÑ,.()!\\-+%$]"
```

> this pass ----> "||°°dafsasdf" but this didnt pass the valid --->
>   "||°°"

Oh, it's because right now as long as a single character in the string matches the regex, it will pass. You have to create a whole pattern match with a defined *start* and *end*.

```
"^[\\w áéíóúñÑ,.()!\\-+%$]*$"
```

Comment: didnt work, this string pass the validator ---> this is a string with !!! simbols |||°°°

Comment: this pass ----> "||°°dafsasdf"

but this didnt pass the valid ---> "||°°"